# How to disable executing scripts in input?

Tags: php

I'm using prepared statements to "post" something on my page, when I write something, it shows without any problems, but when I input text like this :

```
<div style="border:2px solid #000;">Some TEXT</div>
```

It actually styles the output... I tried it on facebook and when I try to do it there, it shows just normal text...(naturally)... What am I supposed to do ? Thanks!

Comment: [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htmlentities()` when displaying the output. This will translate the `<` and `>` characters to entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`, so they'll be rendered literally instead of processed as HTML:

```
echo htmlentites($variable);
```

Comment: 3 minutes to select your answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the PHP [strip_tags](https://php.net/strip_tags) function.

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```